# Using Tkinter Module in python and the background color module not working

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import pyautogui, time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.configure(background='cyan')

root.title("SycoBak's SpamBot")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Spam Bot')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Word')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 120, window=label2)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Amount')
label3.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(200, 160, window=label3)

entry2 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=entry2)

def Spammer ():
  time.sleep(5)
  x = 0
  amount = int(entry2.get())
  word = entry1.get()
  while (amount > x):
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    x=x+1

button2 = tk.Button(text='Start', command=Spammer)
canvas1.create_window(200, 220, window=button2)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is my code, I have no idea why the background color is not changing. I would like someone to help me debug this issue as I am not getting any errors in my console.

Comment: Do you mean it never becomes cyan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see is your canvas taking the space up of the window and hence the color is not seen. How do I prove it? Just resize your window bigger and you'll see the cyan color.

So dont use canvas to show the widgets on screen, instead use layout managers like, `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()`. Here is an simplified example of your core code with `pack()` and no canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='cyan')
root.title("SycoBak's SpamBot")

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
entry1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Spam Bot')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Word') 
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Amount')
label3.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
label3.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry (root) 
entry2.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(text='Start') #i removed the function here as no changes require there
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the grey background you see for the label is the background of the widget, you can set that to cyan too, like:

```
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Spam Bot',bg='cyan') #do same for others too
```